# Play audio if element has active class - jQuery, BX Slider

Tags: jquery, audio, bxslider

I'm using BX Slider to scroll through content, on each slide there needs to be an audio file (currently HTML5) which automatically plays when the corresponding slide is active (i've given the class 'active-slide' to the slide in view). If there is an existing audio file playing it would need to be cancelled/stopped before the new one is loaded.

I can't provide any existing code related to the audio file as I have no idea where to start!

If anyone could help with this it would be greatly appreciated, many thanks.

BXSlider has the following functionality also, if that helps:

http://bxslider.com/options

Edit: Added Existing code.

```
 <ul class="bxslider group">
<li>
  <div class="container" id="section1">
         ...
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="container" id="section2">
    <audio src="/assets/audio/02.mp3" id="section2Audio"></audio>
         ...
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="container" id="section2-1">

    <audio src="/assets/audio/05.mp3" id="section3Audio"></audio>
      ...
  </div>
</li>
```

Slider functions

```
onSlideAfter: function (currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject) {
    console.log(currentSlideHtmlObject);
    $('.active-slide').removeClass('active-slide');
    $('.bxslider>li').eq(currentSlideHtmlObject + 0).addClass('active-slide')},

onSliderLoad: function () {
    $('.bxslider>li').eq(0).addClass('active-slide');},

onSlideNext: function () {
$('audio').each(function(){
        this.pause(); // Stop playing
        this.currentTime = 0; // Reset time
});

$("audio").get(0).play()},
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following Jquery to enable playing audio for :active class

```
$(element).on({
    focus: function (e) {
        if ($(element).hasClass("active-slide")) {
            //play audio
            // $('nonactiveElement').removeClass("active-slide");
            // stop audio on #nonactiveElement 
        }
    },
    blur: function (e) {
        // do something else entirely for blur
    },
    ...
}
```

## Example:

I have created an example in Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VRZR8/1/

```
$('.next').on("click", function() { 
    var activeDiv = $('.active-slide');
    $(activeDiv).removeClass("active-slide");
    $(activeDiv).parent().next().find(".slide").addClass("active-slide");
});


$('.prev').on("click", function() { 
    var activeDiv = $('.active-slide');
    $(activeDiv).removeClass("active-slide");
    $(activeDiv).parent().prev().find(".slide").addClass("active-slide");
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. However, I need the audio file to automatically play in the background without the need to click anything once the containing div has an active class..

Comment: element means you have to put the container div id or class there

Comment: I get the container bit, just not the focus, blur. I'm new to jQuery - for me focus means buttons, a tags etc which there are none of

Comment: focus , blur is an event in jquery like :active, why dont you try this one and let me know... aslo if you can show me your HTML that would give me some idea...

Comment: I've edited the main post to show the code, i've managed to get the first audio file playing when next is clicked, however i need to pause any others playing and only play the file that is within the active slide.

Comment: hope you get the idea now. you can replace the audio play and stop code in that example...